# Does exist an analytic solution for this PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

i'm trying to solve this PDE :
$ \frac{1}{g(x,y)}\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y} = d(x)\frac{1}{h(x,z)}\frac{\partial^2h(x,z)}{\partial z^2} $
Actually it's almost the heat equation but how do you solve this ? i would like to know if i can express $h(x,z) = ...$ et $g(x,y) = ...$ I don't know if there are some analytic solutions.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can be written $ \frac{1}{g(y)}\frac{\partial g(y)}{\partial y} = \frac{d}{h(z)}\frac{\partial^2h(z)}{\partial z^2} $.

Comment: Unfortunately, d, g and h depend of x... :/

Comment: That doesn't matter. Solve for fixed $x$, then vary $x$.

Comment: The left hand side depends on $x$ and $y$, while the right hand side depends on $x$ and $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the separable equation,
$$g_y'(y)=\mu g(y),\\g(y)=c(z)e^{\mu y};$$

$$h_{zz}(z)=\frac\mu d h(z),\\
h(z)=c'(y)e^{\sqrt{\mu/d}z}+c''(y)e^{-\sqrt{\mu/d}z},$$

(for $\mu<0$, consider imaginary exponentials, i.e. $\sin/\cos$)
and the general solution is a sum of terms

$$f_\mu(y,z)=c_\mu e^{\mu y}e^{\pm\sqrt{\mu/d}z},$$ i.e.

$$f_\mu(x,y,z)=c_\mu(x)e^{\mu y}e^{\pm\sqrt{\mu/d(x)}z}.$$